# How should I "dockerize" my web server?

Tags: webserver, docker

I have a server that runs several web services like Nextcloud, phpBB or Ampache together with Postfix, Dovecot, Bind and many others. This is for friends and family so no more than 10 simultaneous users.

I want to "dockerize" everything so that it will be easier to manage and scale up (and also just to learn Docker).

The thing is, I don't like the idea of having multiple instances of Apache for each web services whereas before I had just one with virtual hosts. Is there a more efficient way of doing that?